# Mezclar etiquetas ensamblador, assembly y asm

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Actualmente existen las etiquetas [ensamblador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ensamblador) y [assembly](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) y [asm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asm) que, a mi manera de ver las cosas, debieran ser sinónimos de una única etiqueta.

Creo este hilo para ver que piensa la comunidad. Propongo que se unifiquen todas las preguntas en la etiqueta [asm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asm) y que se creen sinónimos para las etiquetas [assembly](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) y [ensamblador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ensamblador).

Lamentablemente no tengo la puntuación necesaria en las etiquetas para sugerir yo mismo los sinónimos.

Comment: yo que vos, lo traigo a colacion cuando termine la huelga....

Comment: Sé que no es el mejor momento, pero bueno, lo ví hoy y no suelo dejar para otro día las cosas. Veremos si aparece alguien que al menos sugiera los sinónimos. :)

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga respecto a tu comentario, no sería mejor que sigamos produciendo preguntas para que la falta de moderadores se haga relevante? lo comento con respeto y porque no me importa desaparecer un par de días. Pero creo que tiene mas impacto si hay trafico en la web no moderado porque estáis en huelga que si hay un descenso del mismo. Si crees que es mejor que haya un descenso en el trafico dejare de acceder a stack hasta que acabe la huelga

Comment: @Grismak Tu haz lo que tu quieras, el que quieras hacer huelga o no depende de ti, no de lo que te digan los demás. En ningun momento se ha dicho que no se hagan preguntas ni respuestas, lo que se ha dicho es que se deje de moderar el sitio (si es que quieres), a partir de aqui ya es tu decisión

Comment: es mi decisión, pero dado que estoy a favor de la huelga, si la forma de apoyar a los moderadores es precisamente reducir la actividad en el foro lo haré. Evidentemente es mi decisión como podría ser no hacer huelga, pero dentro de ello, me gustaría saber como ayudar en la medida de mis capacidades

Comment: La huelga es de moderacion @Grismak ... las preguntas bajan calidad por si solas...

Answer (score 4):

**Ensamblador** o **assembler** es el programa que realiza la traducción de instrucciones legibles por un humano a binario.

**Assembly language**, **assembler language**, **lenguaje ensamblador** o simplemente **assembly** es el lenguaje del código fuente.

Al parecer estamos acostumbrados a llamar **ensamblador** también al lenguaje. Véase ["Assembly" vs. "Assembler"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1176138/13419694)

No hay dudas en que deberíamos unificar las etiquetas [asm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asm) y [assembly](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly).

Deberíamos tomarnos un tiempo para tomar la decisión más adecuada para [ensamblador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ensamblador). Algunas posibilidades son:

- Establecerlo como sinónimo de 2 [asm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asm) y [assembly](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly).
- Establecerlo como sinónimo de [assembler](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembler)
- Que permanezca independiente y que se pueda utilizar para referirse tanto al lenguaje como al programa.
- Desmotivar su uso en favor a etiquetas más específicas. Por ejemplo [lenguaje-ensamblador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-ensamblador) y referirse al programa directamente por su nombre [nasm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nasm), [gas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas), [masm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm), etc.

Comment: apoyo la ultima opcion.